# Is infinite product with this characteristic convergent?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Given the infinite product of: $$\prod_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n$$
If I could prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$, does it follow that the aforementioned infinite product converges?

Comment: What do you think? What happens with $a_n=1+1/n$?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought of that. I was stuck with $\frac{1}{cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}$ and $xsin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: If you cold prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$ does it follow that $\sum_{n=k}^\infty b_n$ converges?